# Software for deploying images to PC desktops in a small to medium enterprise

Tags: deployment, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically Configure New Computers](https://serverfault.com/questions/347328/automatically-configure-new-computers)

A few colleagues of mine are currently manually configuring and maintaining about 40 desktop computers (Windows 7) on our floor. This is soon to jump to 80 in a big burst, and they're looking for software to make deploying images easier.

Requirements:
 - Unattended installation
 - Images to include software other than OS (Flash, Google Chrome, etc)
 - Deployment via Network/CD/USB
 - Free/Cheap

They don't mind having to play around with command line built in utilities if they exist and are easy enough to use. But we don't have the capital to go out and buy a fully fledged desktop management solution, nor do we want one. Managing updates etc we can revisit later if need be. Our primary concern right now, is rolling out these desktops. When we have a proper support desk for this function, we'll look at better solutions.

Can any software products that meet these requirements be recommended? What would some of the pros and cons be?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft deployment toolkit is the way to go for cheap easy, customizable deployment.  Even if you had system center config manager you'd use MDT.  [MDT 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791)