# Instructions for pushing image from server on a local network

Tags: windows-xp, disk-image

Every fortnight or so we get around 10-20 computers back from clients and we have to wipe them, restore to factory default, and then install a few select pieces of software. It's arduous and time-consuming to sit there with each computer individually and go through this process again and again and it can sometimes take up most of the day.

In my head the idea I have for a better system is that we have a server with a bunch of system images on, so we can stack up a load of computers and connect them to a switch. Then without having to plug in every peripheral into every computer, we can just turn them all on, go to the server and push a selected image to all the systems at the same time.

Sound like a simple, feasible idea? Well after looking for how to do this it turns out either it isn't or it's a well kept secret. Does anyone know (preferably from experience) the best way to do this? The computers (bar the server) will not be continuously connected to our network as we ship them off again once they're ready, so any solution that requires the machines to have any form of client software on is not what we're looking for.

Is it even doable without client software?

Further info:

- Client comps use Windows XP

Comment: In your research did you come across information regarding using [PXE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.07.desktopfiles.aspx) and Windows deployment services for pushing out images?  This is included in Windows so I would look there first.  The other option is a solution such as an Acronis server or third party software, which you must pay for.  We use Symantec Ghost here and it works well.  Depending on your budget I'd start by looking into the PXE and Deployment services, especially if you're wanting network deploys.

Comment: I did come across PXE but from what I gathered this was to boot a copy of Windows over a network, when actually I want to re-image the HDD over a network that these computers will only be on once. Does PXE allow me to do this or will I have to get third party software? I looked at the FOG project but it looks like they stopped updating it years ago.

Comment: I've had colleagues use PXE to install Windows machines before with answer files or unattended install images.  May want to look at Symantec Ghost or other third party tools as well.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for WDS.  I've also used Altiris Deployment Solution, which is pricey, or you could look into other imaging and backup tools like Ghost or Acronis.  My company was using Acronis with external hard drives for a specific type of new computer until I set up WDS.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Do you have a link to any walkthroughs you used to setup WDS?  We may be moving that direction in the near future as well.

Comment: This was the main one I used since I was familiar with Altiris.  http://justin-bennett-msjc.blogspot.com/2010/03/moved-from-altiris-deployment-solution.html

Comment: Almost a dupe of [Automatically Configure New Computers](http://serverfault.com/questions/347328/automatically-configure-new-computers). Tons of information in that Q&A. You've got a lot to learn, especially if you don't have someone around to bounce questions off. Also, all support for XP ends in a couple months (including security patches) - It's long past time to upgrade.

Comment: WDS is fairly easy to set up, as long as you have a domain and you control the DHCP servers. I'd way this is the way to go (although I'd highly, HIGHLY suggest you start upgrading them to Windows 7).

Comment: Also, a tool of mine from back in the day before WDS was useful, [FoG - Free Open Source Ghost.](http://www.fogproject.org/)  Really no shortage of tools in this arena.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of PXE, WDS and Clonezilla.

If you want to deploy XP from an image over a network then look at this link
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj648426.aspx
+Pro

- Drivers can be added to WDS server and applied only to the correct system
- Images will deploy quickly over gigabit (our 60GB dev image takes sub 30 minutes from reboot to fully working system)
- Taking images is semi automated
- Once setup the user interface to deploy is nearly idiot proof
- Answer files allow almost complete automation (Think language, key, location, disk partitions )

-Con

- Takes a lot of work to get going, you need DHCP, and WDS service as a bare minimum to work on the server and the Windows Deployment Kit to make the deployment and master images
- Answer files have cryptic manuals especially about locale settings

However you may find it quicker (to get setup) taking images with Clonezilla to a USB disk
http://clonezilla.org

+Pro

- A Clonezilla CD and a USB disk are all you need

-Con

- Driver issues with windows where the master and the image are not the same hardware :(
- Not the nicest of interfaces

*Very important that you remember to sysprep the master computer just before you take the image or neither will do what you expect.*
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577